# How to recover pgp keys from a Windows.old directory as of September 2023?

Tags: windows, pgp, gpg4win, kleopatra

This question has been asked before but whether or not the process works seems to be dependent on the software versions involved.  I've tried them all and none work.

Does anyone know how I would recover my old keys (both private keys of mine and public keys of others) for use in Kleopatra preferably, but I'm open to switching to another key manager if anyone can help.

Comment: Where exactly were they located in your original profile?

Comment: Restore the last full image to another disk, boot and and recover them from that image.

Comment: I don't have an image, only a windows.old directory that contains the \User\ directory.  It has  the \gnupg\ directory which itself has a \private-keys-v1.d\ directory that has .key files in it but Kleopatra doesn't do anything with these files.